# include php file if page_id matches

Tags: plugin-development, include

I think this is a simple question:

I'm building a plugi, and up until now, if i wanted to include a php file, i would have to know the page_id - i would put the following command in page.php (or whatever page template i'm using):

```
if (is_page(4552)) {
     include WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/file_to_include.php';
}
```

now, A bit more background: i now have a hook that creates a post on activation, and saves the post_id using update_options. so, that's how i know what $page_id is.

So, to summarize - **how do i dynamically write the code above - in my plugin - assuming I know the $page_id**?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add it to a hook that fires at or after 'wp' ;

Example:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'your_function_name');

function your_function_name(){
    global $post;

$your_page_id = get_option('your_option_name');

    if( $post->ID == $your_page_id ):
//your include 
endif;
}
```

Comment: hmm, that's good, but it doesn't work - it loads my html before EVERYTHING, even the DOCTYPE.....

Comment: I didn't realize that your include was html output.  Where do you want it to show up? (in the header, right after the body tag?)

Comment: right after the body tag sounds perfect :)

Comment: Could you let me know what theme you are using, because that would change what the earliest hook after the opening body tag would be

Comment: You could try 'the_post' in place of 'wp'.  that might work for you

Comment: 'the_post' didn't work - threw it in the middle, between link and meta. i'm using whiteboard as my theme... thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: I ended up using 'loop_end' as my hook - thank you!